# Unable to receive via QUdpSocket multicast

Tags: c++, qt

Unable to receive via QUdpSocket multicast.
To be precise, it cannot be received if the Internet is enabled.
However, it may work fine on other PCs. (Some PCs don't work.)
There is no significant difference in those environments.
On Wireshark, I could see the data and on SocketDebugger, I could receive it.
Why is this so strange?

My environment
OS: Windows10
Qt: 5.15.0 MinGW
Peripheral equipment: LUD-U3-AGH

udp.ccp

```
void Udp::fnUdpSetting(QString localIP,quint16 multicastPort,QString multicastIP)
{
    m_pUdpSockRecv = new QUdpSocket(this);

    connect(m_pUdpSockRecv, SIGNAL( readyRead() ), this, SLOT( fnUdpRecvData() ));

    if( m_pUdpSockRecv->bind( QHostAddress( localIP ) , multicastPort, QUdpSocket::DefaultForPlatform) ){
        if( m_pUdpSockRecv->joinMulticastGroup( QHostAddress( multicastIP ) )) {
            qDebug() << "Connection Success";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Join Error";
        }
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Bind Error";
    }
}

void Udp::fnUdpRecvData()
{
    qDebug() << "OK";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a possible firewall issue.  Is your firewall configured to allow ip multicast packets through?

Comment: @G.M. yes,firewall is Invalidation.